# jquery menu ul li

Tags: jquery-selectors

i have a tree menu that i need to open on specific branch.
1. on click on an A element i open the all next UL.
now i want to close all other UL exept the ones that are parents of the A element.

2. i want to write a function that will get an argument that is a A ID and will open the menu in the right place.

my jquery code

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $(".solmenu").click(function() {
              $(this).nextAll("ul").slideToggle();

        });
```

my css

```
ul.solmenu_3140_1 {display:none;}
ul.solmenu_3140_2 {display:none;}
```

my html

```
<ul class="solmenu_3140_0"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">1</a> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">11</a> 
        <ul class="solmenu_3140_2"> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">111</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">112</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">113</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">114</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">115</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">116</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">117</a> 
          </li> 
        </ul> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">12</a> 
        <ul class="solmenu_3140_2"> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">121</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">122</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">123</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">124</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">125</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">126</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">127</a> 
          </li> 
        </ul> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">13</a> 
        <ul class="solmenu_3140_2"> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">131</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">132</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">133</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">134</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">135</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">136</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">137</a> 
          </li> 
        </ul> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> 
<ul class="solmenu_3140_0"> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">2</a> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">21</a> 
      </li> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">22</a> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> 
<ul class="solmenu_3140_0"> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">3</a> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">31</a> 
      </li> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">32</a> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> 
<ul class="solmenu_3140_0"> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">4</a> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">5</a> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">6</a> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">7</a> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">8</a> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">81</a> 
      </li> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">82</a> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> 
<ul class="solmenu_3140_0"> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">9</a> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">91</a> 
        <ul class="solmenu_3140_2"> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">911</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">912</a> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">913</a> 
          </li> 
          </ul> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul class="solmenu_3140_1"> 
      <li> 
        <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">92</a> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> 
<ul class="solmenu_3140_0"> 
  <li> 
    <a class="solmenu" href="javascript:void(0);">10</a> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

[example of my code](http://img2.timg.co.il/forums/1_141010974.html)

Comment: Please post code in your question.

Comment: If you want to write it, just go ahead and write it. If you don't know how, then post your code and we'll put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you may want to trigger a click event on a specific node

see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/